# Pass environment/input argument to command argument in step function

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, amazon-eks, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to setup a step function with an `EKS run` job. The job kicks off a pod in an EKS cluster and execute commands. As a start, I want the command to be `echo $S3_BUCKET $S3_KEY`, where both `$S3_BUCKET` and `$S3_KEY` are environment variables passed in from the step function input. Here is the container spec:

```
                "containers": [
                  {
                    "name": "my-container-spec",
                    "image": "****.dkr.ecr.****.amazonaws.com/****:latest",
                    "command": [
                      "echo"
                    ],
                    "args": [
                      "$S3_BUCKET", "$S3_KEY"
                    ],
                    "env": [
                      {
                        "name": "S3_BUCKET",
                        "value.$": "$.s3_bucket"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "S3_KEY",
                        "value.$": "$.s3_key"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "restartPolicy": "Never"
```

Unfortunately, after the job is executed, the command only echo the raw test `$S3_BUCKET $S3_KEY` instead of the passed in value.

So the question here is how I should pass in an environment variable as an `args`. The environment variable doesn't have to be passed in, it could be other inherited variables.

Comment: A common mistake; you can either switch your `command:` to invoke a shell, which will then honor the _shell variables_ or switch your references to use [the kubernetes reference syntax](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#use-environment-variables-to-define-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick: `args: ["$(S3_BUCKET), $(S3_KEY)"]`